# Customize live Ubuntu / Lubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system, usb

I know that variations of this question have been asked multiple times and answered in a variety of ways. While I am digging through the options online I thought I would ask the SO community.

I am looking to build a live Ubuntu/Lubuntu USB stick so that I can put it in the back of a computer and just have it boot to the desktop without prompts. I would like ti to work on multiple computers with varying pieces of hardware. I am not sure if installing the OS directly on the USB would lose some of that functionality. Below are a list of some of what I am aiming for. After I have configured the USB the way I want it I will make multiple copies for different users.

1. Live Ubuntu / Lubuntu usb
2. Boot to desktop without prompting
3. Changes would be persistent
4. Would be able to work on a variety of computers with different hardware configurations. (Will use 32bit to facilitate 32 and 64)
5. I want to customize (add / remove) software to the live image.

Answer (score 0):

I've attacked the same problem recently, this is what you need:

1. Lubuntu 16.04 was the best option I could fine after considering different distros and versions, it provides robust, lightweight and fast live USB installation.

2-3. Burn iso file with UNetbootin, and specify some 1-2GB in the `Space used...` box, now your live version is persistent. To disable prompting: access the drive, make a copy of `syslinux.cfg` (just in case), edit the original file and replace its entire content by this portion of text that you will find in `/isolinux/txt.cfg`:

```
default live  
label live  
  menu label ^Try Lubuntu without installing  
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz  
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash ---
```

adding `persistent` to the last line, it should look like:

```
append file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper persistent initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash noprompt --
```

4. This distro has worked just fine for me in a number of old and new computers. Yes, 32bit iso preferred.
5. Proceed as you need, but adding (`sudo apt-get install`) or deleting (`sudo apt-get remove`) the packages you want, everything will be kept as it is after you (safely) shut down the computer.

Now, you only need to operate the `dd` command to make your iso file and start cloning (or order USB drives with prestored data to your dealer).